# Pear version returning wrong version @pear_version@

Tags: php, pear

I am using pear 1-9-5 in windows with php 5.6.4. In command line when i execute command in CMD `pear version` it returns

```
PEAR Version: @pear_version@
PHP Version: 5.6.4
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0
Running on: Windows NT LENOVO-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586
```

google don't helps also!! I need to know why I am getting this and how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a git installation, not an official release.

Only in an official release the `@pear_version@` tag is replaced with the installed version.

Comment: it is coded by php so, there should be some way to replace this `@pear_version@` by version number as i khow which version i am using. can you tell me that system?

Comment: yes, but i think somewhere it is written in some script. it is not compiled software. so i think by editing some script i can actually solve this.